# Accessing Microsoft Graph api after authenticating into my own application

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, active-directory, jwt

I have my own application, call it appA, that I registered with Azure Active Directory.  I authenticate users into appA using the authorization code grant process outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code. I specify the resource the Jwt to be good for as appA during this process. After a user enters credentials, I get an authorization code, then use that code to get a Jwt and a refresh token good for appA.

Once users are authenticated into my application, I want to inspect the groups they are in for role based access control.  The groups are not returned in the token because each user has more than 5 groups.

This forces me to make an additional call to the graph Api to get groups for a certain user. But, in order to do this, I need to use the refresh token and specify the https://graph.microsoft.com as the resource to the token refresh endpoint.  The token I am returned is now good to make requests against the graph Api.

My question is: how can I make the call inside appA to get the token good for the graph api?  It seems like I will have to juggle multiple Jwts at the same time and I am having a hard time conceptualizing how this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I make the call inside appA to get the token good for the
>   graph api?

You could directly request the token for the MS graph API, which just needs to change the resource value for MS graph API (https://graph.microsoft.com) in the OAuth 2.0 code grant flow.

In the **Request an authorization code**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=<client-id-value>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=<redirect-uri-value>
&response_mode=query
&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
&state=12345
```

The response like this:
[image]
In the **Use the authorization code to request an access token**

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=<client-id-value>
&code=<code-value>
&redirect_uri=<redirect-uri-value>
&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
&client_secret=<key-value>
```

The response like this:
[image]

Then you could use the access_token to make requests against the MS graph API.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the same flow working in my application now. Wouldn't I then need to keep track of two access tokens in my application since the graph access token won't work for my application because it is a different resource? One for the graph API, and one for my application itself? How would that work out?

Comment: Yes, different resource needs different acess_token. For example, if you just want to make a request for the MS graph API, you just need to request the token for MS graph API.  And then if you need to access other API, you could directly use the refresh token to request the new access_token for others.